# Disk Based Text Editor to Edit File Larger than Memory

Tags: linux, text-editors, text-editing

I am using Ubuntu and looking for a good editor to edit a file that is > 4GB. I just need to put content at the end and beginning of the file. I suppose I could use something like

```
cat "text to add" >> huge_file
```

To append to the file. Is that the route to go? What about prepending? In general, what is the best route if I wanted to edit somewhere in the middle?

I've tried VIM and it fails miserably. I assume emacs and nano would be even worse. What else is there? I assume to accomplish what I am looking for, the editor would have to be specifically designed for this by not keeping the entirety of the file's contents in memory.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you have so much data in a text file. Not the most manageable format for big data, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a partial answer, but yes, if you are simply appending I would use:

```
cat extra.txt >> huge_file.txt
```

or

```
echo "Single line to add" >> huge_file.txt
```

For prepending I would do:

```
cat extra.txt huge_file.txt > huge_file_new.txt
```

Comment: This is what I wound up using, but would be nice if there was a more robust method.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to append, then `>>huge_file` is much better than what any editor can do, because it won't touch the existing data. Inserting data into a file requires rewriting everything after the insertion point, so it'll be slow even with the right tools.

With vim, make sure you try with the [LargeFile plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506).

[Bvi](http://bvi.sourceforge.net) is a version of vi that targets binary files. It can edit a slice of a file (i.e. from position x to position y).

The [wikipedia editor comparison page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) has a column with large file support. The situation is pretty bleak.

Comment: Vim should be able to handle files of up to 2 Gb on a 32 bit system. I think the comparison page lists it as 2^32 (4 Gb) not sure if that's correct in all versions of vim.

Comment: AFAIK support for files over 2GB on a 32-bit system is new in the soon-to-be-released vim 7.3 ([patch 7.2.413](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_dev@googlegroups.com/msg08979.html)), though I don't know what you can do with a file that doesn't fit in the process address space.

Answer (score 2):

Ultraedit is the only editor that does this well.  I would, also, prefer an OSS.  One doesn't exist.  I'm particularly surprised that this isn't a capability of vi... it's such a swiss army knife.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I found this via google looking for something similar this is another method I found.

Situation: You have a 4.0 GB file and you need to edit line number 120.

Solution: Using head and tail to get everything except the line you want to edit.

```
# cat origfile.txt 
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
# head -n 5 origfile.txt >> newfile.txt
# echo "line 6" >> newfile.txt 
# tail -n +7 origfile.txt >> newfile.txt 
# cat newfile.txt 
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 line 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
```

From my testing tail will not load the entire file into memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com) is capable of editing a file without loading it into memory. I haven't tested the Linux version of it yet, and neither have I tested a >4GB file, so I cannot give any guarantees, but I edited some huge (~1.5 GB) files with the Windows version (and long ago, too).

Comment: I would prefer OSS if possible.